# Function.curried not defined

Tags: eclipse, scala, currying

The following Scala code works for me:

```
def curry(s1: String)(s2: String): String = (s1 + " " + s2).toUpperCase
val uncurry = Function.uncurried(curry _)
println(uncurry("short", "pants"))
```

However the following code does not:

```
def cat(s1: String, s2: String): String = (s1 + " " + s2).toUpperCase    
def curry = Function.curried (cat _) 
println(curry("short")("pants"))
```

The above gives me a compiler error (in Eclipse)

> value curried is not a member of object Function

And indeed, intellisense in Eclipse is also missing the curried function on the Function object... Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `curried` would take, for example, a function `(A, B) => C` and turn it into `A => B => C`.
The actual currying and the resulting function depends on the amount of parameters. And currying for only one parameter is not defined, as just results in the same function.
So, `curried` is not defined on the `Function` object, but on `Function2`, `Function3`, and so on. That means, you want to write:

```
def cat(s1: String, s2: String): String = (s1 + " " + s2).toUpperCase
val curry = (cat _).curried
println(curry("short")("pants"))
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'm guessing this must have changed between Scala 2.7 and 2.11 (in the text book I'm reading they use `Function.curried(cat _)`. In any case, I prefer the new syntax :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's not on the `Function` object, but on the `Function2`–`Function22` types.

```
def curry = (cat _).curried
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a method on the function itself

```
def cat(s1: String, s2: String): String = (s1 + " " + s2).toUpperCase
        //> cat: (s1: String, s2: String)String
def curry = (cat _).curried
        //> curry: => String => (String => String)
println(curry("short")("pants"))
        //> SHORT PANTS
```